# Video Processing frame-by-frame at user prompt

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, video-processing

I am looking to process some video data, and would like to do it frame-by-frame. I wish to see results of each frame, so would want there to be pause between frame-processing, broken by user input (probably a key).

Is there efficient ways to achieve this aim in Python?
This is my current code, and at the moment it goes on without I am not sure if this is the best way to do so?

**EDIT: ** I've changed the code to achieve my aim. Just needed to add another line of waitKey command. :p

```
import cv2
import scipy.ndimage as ndimage

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("#Some_Video")

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    fil_im = ndimage.correlate(gray, '#Some_filter')
    cv2.imshow('filtered figure', fil_im)

    k = cv2.waitKey(0)
    if k == 27:
            break
    elif k == 32:
            continue
    # Continues to the next frame on 'space', quits the loop on 'esc' key.

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `cv2.waitKey(0)` for pausing an iteration of the while loop. The argument 0 implies that the code will wait indefinitely for you to press a key before moving to the next line of code.

Modify the code as:

```
while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    fil_im = ndimage.correlate(gray, '#Some_filter')
    cv2.imshow('filtered figure', fil_im)
    cv2.waitKey(0)# waits for user prompt here 

    if cv2.waitKey(0) == 'b':
            break
            #breaks while loop only if you press b, else it goes to next iteration
```

Comment: Thanks! I did make use of two waitKey commands. One for proceeding to the next frame, one for stopping the loop altogether.

Comment: I hope that answers your question, considering the downvote

Comment: Not sure why you got a downvote. :S But at least I gave one upvote.